# Removing rows based on a vector

Tags: r, vector

Given a matrix (m),
I want to remove from it the subjects given by a changing vector,
I am trying to do a loop but it does only remove the last input:

```
m= matrix(1:4,10,3);

changing_vector = c(2,1) or c(1,4) # etc..

for(j in 1:length(changing_vector))
{
    a = subData[!(subData$subject== changing_vector [j]),]
}
```

Someone know why it does not work? Do you propose any other way to do it?

Thanks in advance for your help,

G.

Comment: What does it mean by subData? What's the relationship of it with the matrix m? What is the subData$subject? And is a your desired result? From your code, you didn't do things recursively or iteratively,  a is just the result of removing the last subject j.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to post reproducible examples, that others can see what you are trying to do. Also try to be very precise, as it is sometimes very hard to understand what people want to do (as in your case).

Maybe this can help you with your promlem:

```
m <- matrix(1:5, 15, 5)       
vec <- c(x,y)

    for(i in 1:nrow(m)){
      z[i] <- any(m[i,] %in% vec)
    }

 m <-   m[!x,]
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your help, but altough it did not work to solve the issue, here what I did:

```
# removing subjects who did not reach a performance> 70 % (for ex.- easier to # understand this way

subjectsTOremove= which((performance<70)

vector_poz = c();
for(j in 1:length(subjectsTOremove))
{
  S_to_remove= subjectsTOremove[j]
  a = data[!(data$subject== S_to_remove),]

  aa = which(data$subid == subjectsTOremove[j])
  vector_poz = c(vector_poz,aa)
}

# then this subjects rows are transformed in NaN and the NaN removed
data[vector_poz,]=NaN # this tranf allows to check visually the data out
data= data[complete.cases(data),]
```